# c++ error converting *char to int

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-conversion

I have a char array that I need converted to int so that I can do math against the values.
Right now the closest I can get is  ->  error: request for member 'str' in 'myData', which is of non-class type 'char*'

code:

```
char *getmyData()
{
        static char buff[BUFSIZ];
        FILE *fp = popen("php script.php 155", "r");
        std::fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp);
        return buff;
}

void mathFunc(){
        char *myData = getmyData();
        for (int i = 0; myData[i]; ++i) {
                int x;
                const char * cstr2 = myData.str().c_str();
                cstr2 >> x;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                        cout << x[i] + 10;
        }
}
```

error:

```
 # g++ -g myDataunfuck.cpp -o myDataunfuck.o -std=gnu++11 -lcurl
myDataunfuck.cpp: In function 'void mathFunc()':
myDataunfuck.cpp:30:31: error: request for member 'str' in 'myData', which is of non-class type 'char*'
myDataunfuck.cpp:31:12: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'int' to binary 'operator>>'
myDataunfuck.cpp:32:23: error: 'size' was not declared in this scope
myDataunfuck.cpp:33:15: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
myDataunfuck.cpp:44:1: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
myDataunfuck.cpp:47:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

[complete code](https://bpaste.net/show/bc09aa8b12df)

Comment: What do you expect `cstr2 >> x` to do? And with `myData`, that is ` C string. No methods or members! Are you getting confused with `std::string` and how to use it?

Comment: It appears that your request for the member 'str' in 'myData' couldn't compile, since 'char*' is not a class type. I think the compiler message is pretty clear?

Comment: @crashmstr convert to int, but I am sure I have to put it into a loop first. that is mainly a brain reminder for an issue I am still trying to solve.

Comment: @BrianCain  the data being converted  ->  https://bpaste.net/show/4ac9550d2281

Comment: @BradS it does not work like that. `char *` has no members or methods, and does not override or implement `operator >>`.

Comment: @BrianCain with this code ->  https://bpaste.net/show/5c6e8827765a  I appear to be able to print out the first item in my array as an int. If this is the case, I only need to figure out how to print the rest. my loop seems to be missing data  https://bpaste.net/show/4ac9550d2281

Comment: The first comment references your class name but I'd like to note that variable names of this ilk will not reflect well upon you professionally.  I'm sure I'll get shouted down about this, pointed to meta or something else; just note that people always end up bitten in the ass by this practice - it never ends well. P.S. I'm most assuredly not a prude, quite the opposite in fact - just a warning from one professional to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:-

```
const char * cstr2 = myData;
```

Comment: That got it. It says I have to wait 12 min to click the button. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myData` variable is a primitive `char*` type. It does not have any methods accessible by `.`.